# Hibernate caching . problem with backdoor

Tags: hibernate, caching, jakarta-ee

In our java/j2ee app we have hibernate and hibernate caching is enabled . But because of some business reasons we MUST also have a kind of a backdoor that we should be able to update some columns from the database .

When we are doing so the hibernate cache is not getting updated . So the only option we are now left with is restarting the application (running on jboss 6).

Now this is happening on CIT/staging environment . And the app moves to live on coming Monday , and there it will be impossible for obvious reasons to restart an app.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this ? (apart from disabling hibernate cache . That is my final fall back solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it directly in the DB.  Create a secured page in the app which does what you want, through Hibernate.  Its a baaaad idea to directly update live DB's, as you can mess things up very easily.  This controlled page will limit damage yet still allow you to do what you need to do.

Comment: Again .. this is out of question for now . I can have a separate discussion if you like for why :) .  Those kind of things are planned for next 6 months 2 be developed . But Is there any way I can accomplish this without a web page/ restarting the app ?

Comment: I don't think so.  Directly updating the DB goes outside Hibernate, so its cache will have no knowledge of those updates.  This is a classic issue with caches.

Comment: You could clear the cache (using SessionFactory.getCache().evictXxx) after updating the DB (using some administration URL), but the cache would be stale during the whole DB update process.